# ActiveMQ is not starting

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have downloaded the ActiveMQ zip file on my windows system and extracted it. Then I tried to run the activemq.bat file and it is not getting started. It is showing the following shared log file, Can any one tell me what is the issue and what needs to be done to start the activeMQ,

```
D:\apache-activemq-5.11.1\bin>activemq.bat
Java Runtime: Oracle Corporation 1.7.0_51 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre
  Heap sizes: current=1005568k  free=995061k  max=1005568k
    JVM args: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Xms1G -Xmx1G -Djava.util.logging.c
onfig.file=logging.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config=D:\apache-active
mq-5.11.1\bin\..\conf\login.config -Dactivemq.classpath=D:\apache-activemq-5.11.
1\bin\..\conf;D:\apache-activemq-5.11.1\bin\../conf;D:\apache-activemq-5.11.1\bi
n\../conf; -Dactivemq.home=D:\apache-activemq-5.11.1\bin\.. -Dactivemq.base=D:\a
pache-activemq-5.11.1\bin\.. -Dactivemq.conf=D:\apache-activemq-5.11.1\bin\..\co
nf -Dactivemq.data=D:\apache-activemq-5.11.1\bin\..\data -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\apa
che-activemq-5.11.1\bin\..\data\tmp
Extensions classpath:
  [D:\apache-activemq-5.11.1\bin\..\lib,D:\apache-activemq-5.11.1\bin\..\lib\cam
el,D:\apache-activemq-5.11.1\bin\..\lib\optional,D:\apache-activemq-5.11.1\bin\.
.\lib\web,D:\apache-activemq-5.11.1\bin\..\lib\extra]
ACTIVEMQ_HOME: D:\apache-activemq-5.11.1\bin\..
ACTIVEMQ_BASE: D:\apache-activemq-5.11.1\bin\..
ACTIVEMQ_CONF: D:\apache-activemq-5.11.1\bin\..\conf
ACTIVEMQ_DATA: D:\apache-activemq-5.11.1\bin\..\data
Usage: Main [--extdir <dir>] [task] [task-options] [task data]

Tasks:
    browse                   - Display selected messages in a specified destinat
ion.
    bstat                    - Performs a predefined query that displays useful
statistics regarding the specified broker
    create                   - Creates a runnable broker instance in the specifi
ed path.
    decrypt                  - Decrypts given text
    dstat                    - Performs a predefined query that displays useful
tabular statistics regarding the specified destination type
    encrypt                  - Encrypts given text
    export                   - Exports a stopped brokers data files to an archiv
e file
    list                     - Lists all available brokers in the specified JMX
context
    purge                    - Delete selected destination's messages that match
es the message selector
    query                    - Display selected broker component's attributes an
d statistics.
    start                    - Creates and starts a broker using a configuration
 file, or a broker URI.
    stop                     - Stops a running broker specified by the broker na
me.

Task Options (Options specific to each task):
    --extdir <dir>  - Add the jar files in the directory to the classpath.
    --version       - Display the version information.
    -h,-?,--help    - Display this help information. To display task specific he
lp, use Main [task] -h,-?,--help

Task Data:
    - Information needed by each specific task.

JMX system property options:
    -Dactivemq.jmx.url=<jmx service uri> (default is: 'service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/r
mi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi')
    -Dactivemq.jmx.user=<user name>
    -Dactivemq.jmx.password=<password>
```

Comment: Looks like some arguments are missing

Comment: which arguments? IS that an issue in activemq bundle or in my classpath?

Comment: Do not know. But if the programm shows you the `usage` of a program than in most cases arguments are missing

Comment: Any work around to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must start ActiveMQ by command:

activemq-admin.bat start

activemq.bat is for managment, that's why you have set arguments

Comment: great it is started. How can I access it in browser, Is it http://localhost:61613

Comment: Hi @Vinod

Activemq url is http://localhost:8161/ to access from browser